# How to escape \ in webiew links (Android)?

Tags: android, webview

> Hi, I am getting HTML data from the server in the following format :

```
<p>I don&#39;t know what does it want. <a href=\"https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView\">wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView</a></p>
```

> The issue is the link `<a href=\"https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView\">` doesnt work in webview. I think its because of the `\` in the start of the URL

> This is my webview sample code :

```
String text = "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/myfonts/Poppins-Regular_0.ttf\")}body,* {font-family: MyFont; color:#7A7B7D; font-size: 13px;}img{max-width:100%;height:auto; border-radius: 3px;}</style>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", text + "<div>" + objBean.getNewsDesc() + "</div>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

> Can anyone give a technique or process, so i can escape `\` if present in any link in webiew. Thanks in advance

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "escape" the backslashes. These are used to escape the double quotes in the HTML you got from the server. You need to remove them (for this purpose, although this may cause you other problems). I've no idea why you would get HTML that looks like this.

Anyway, you just need to remove them to make the HTML parse properly. Something like:

```
String badHtml = "..." // Your HTML from the server
String okHtml = badHtml.replace('\\', '');
```